# compilation issue with NDK

Tags: compilation, android-ndk, armv7

I am compiling one file using NDK android-ndk-5rc,

here is command

/media/Softwares/android-ndk-r5c/ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=android-8

but facing one strange compilation error

Fatal error: invalid -march= option: `armv5te'
make: *** [/media/Softwares/Projects/FilterTest/obj/local/armeabi/objs/convolution/convolution.o] Error 1

i searched armv5te in whole folder android-ndk-r5c and modified to armv7-a, still facing same error.

Any help is great....

Comment: i tried as told in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770296/error-while-compiling-android-jni-sample-invalid-march-option-armv5te?rq=1

Comment: I resolved it, it was just permission problem on ndk folder.